# How Setup Azure AD and Cypress so SSO Login works

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cypress

I try to automate testing with cypress.
For the app to work the user needs to login.
So i try to automate this step.

I wrote following command which i pass in the username password.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', ( userId, pwd ) => { 
    const domain = 'XXXX'
    const clientId = 'XXXX'
    const clientSecret = 'XXXX'
    const scope = 'XXXX'
    cy.request({
        method:'POST',
        url:`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${domain}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
        header:
        {
           'cache-control': 'no-cache',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: true,
        body: {
           grant_type: 'password',
           client_id: clientId,
           client_secret: clientSecret,
           password: pwd,
           scope: scope,
           username: userId
        }
 })
 .then((resp)=>{
     const token = resp.body['access_token']
     console.log(token)
     //cy.visit('http://{URL}/auth/#access_token='+token)
 })
})
```

With this i get the error message back. That the Username or password is wrong.

Anyone knows how to fix this? or know a better way to setup Cypress with a SSO from azure AD?

Comment: Could you double-check your username and password to make sure they are correct? And is your account MFA-enabled?

Comment: The accepted answer for the following question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64822167/6135684

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure AD ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) should work, when using it, make sure you are using a work account whose format is `xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`, and it is not MFA-enabled, details see screenshot below. If you don't have such an account, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory#add-a-new-user) to create one.

[image]

In your case, please double-check the username and password, make sure they are correct.(If they are correct, please make sure there is no escape issue in the actual request.)

I test the flow in the postman, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. if im correct SSO works with ADFS